# duplicate items in type reflection(?)

Tags: c#, reflection, types

Given the following, code why do I get duplicate items?

```
Type intType = typeof(Int32);
foreach(var v in intType.GetMethods())
Console.WriteLine(v.Name);
```

For example `ToString()` appears 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it returns all the overloads of the String method from the Struct Int32

[image]

Comment: Thanks, A picture is worth a thousand words :)

Answer (score 4):

Because [Int32.ToString() has four overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k9ccxf6.aspx). You can easily see this by setting a breakpoint and inspect the `intType.GetMethods()` result, where you'll see (among others):

```
[5] {System.String ToString()}
[6] {System.String ToString(System.String)}
[7] {System.String ToString(System.IFormatProvider)}
[8] {System.String ToString(System.String, System.IFormatProvider)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because [`Type.GetMethods()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt2ztzdc.aspx) returns *all overloads* methods of this type.

[`Int32.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k9ccxf6.aspx) method has 4 overloads, so...

```
System.String ToString()
System.String ToString(System.String)
System.String ToString(System.IFormatProvider)
System.String ToString(System.String, System.IFormatProvider)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that there are **more** to a method, than just a name:

```
Type intType = typeof(Int32);

foreach(var v in intType.GetMethods())
    Console.WriteLine(v.Name + " " +
                     (v.IsStatic? "static " : "") +
                      string.Join(", ", v.GetParameters()
                                         .Select(p => p.ParameterType.Name + " " + p.Name)));
```

will print

```
CompareTo Object value
CompareTo Int32 value
Equals Object obj
Equals Int32 obj
GetHashCode 
ToString 
ToString String format
ToString IFormatProvider provider
ToString String format, IFormatProvider provider
Parse static String s
Parse static String s, NumberStyles style
Parse static String s, IFormatProvider provider
Parse static String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider
TryParse static String s, Int32& result
TryParse static String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider, Int32& result
GetTypeCode 
GetType
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely its the whole inheritance tree. Try passing `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` to `GetMethods`.